# Mono 2.8.2 and loading PNG files

Tags: c#, image-processing, mono, png

I'm doing a project that adds and multiplies multiple layers of PNGs and generated Bitmap objects to each other in Mono 2.8.2.

I'm having a problem where the pixels being loaded from the PNG, which are (253, 252, 252, 153) (RGBA) are coming in as (151, 151, 151, 153). This is with *no* modifications to the PNG, just loading it and looping over the x/y coords while printing out the pixels. It looks like it's pulling the correct alpha, but not the correct color values.

EDIT - This is the image I'm working with https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr21x.png

This is more or less what I'm doing:

```
Bitmap cover = new Bitmap("test.png");
for(int x = 0; x < cover.Width; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < cover.Height; y++)
    {
        Color pixel = cover.GetPixel(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}x{1}: {2} {3} {4} {5}", x, y, pixel.R, pixel.G, pixel.B, pixel.A)
    }
}
```

I've verified the values I'm checking in GIMP. Any thoughts on this? I'm developing on Linux, Mono 2.8.2, libgdiplus-2.10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=679242. Apparently there is an open bug report for this very problem.

In the interim, any PNG that's mostly-white with alpha can be inverted in an image-editing program (so it's mostly-black), loaded, and re-inverted in the code. A pain in the ass, but a suitable workaround, unless your PNG contains white AND black alpha values, or god forbid colors.

EDIT: a better way is to just unmultiply the color values, as stated in the bug report (note this only works if alpha is non-zero):

```
r|g|b *= 255.0 / (double)alpha;
```

This can be tested for by creating a white one-pixel PNG with an alpha value of 150 (or something). Load the image, and test its one pixel for a r/g/b value less than 255. If found, unmultiply all the alpha values for ALL of your loaded PNGs. If not found, load your PNGs normally (no need to fix). This way even if the mono bug is fixed, your image manipulation won't change or break in any way.